Patch Creation and PCA for HSI classification causing the System RAM on Colab GPU to crash
I'm working on a hyperspectral image classification project using PyTorch. My architecture involves creating patches for each pixel in the image using a window of a specified patch size (e.g., 13x13, 15x15). The WHU-Hi dataset I'm using provides official training and testing splits through masks, where pixel locations are indicated by a value of 1 (0 otherwise).
To generate the training and testing data, I create patches only at the specified positions using the CreateImageCubesWithMask function, followed by applying PCA on the training patches. To prevent data leakage, I apply the same PCA transformation to the testing patches before initializing the training and testing loaders. For the final classification of the entire scene, I apply PCA to the original full dataset and then create patches for every pixel using the CreateImageCubes function.
This process worked fine when I used a Colab TPU, which offers a system RAM of 334 GB. However, since I'm using PyTorch, the TPU execution is quite slow. I tried switching to Colab's GPU, which is faster, but the system RAM is limited to 50 GB. This limitation causes the process to crash, likely due to insufficient memory during the patch creation and storage steps.
How to optimise this workflow so that it can run on Colab's GPU without crashing? Please find snippet of the code code below:
def applyPCA(X_train, X_test, pca_components=30):
    newX_train = np.reshape(X_train, (-1, X_train.shape[-1])).astype(np.float32)
    newX_test = np.reshape(X_test, (-1, X_test.shape[-1])).astype(np.float32)

    pca = PCA(n_components=pca_components, whiten=True)
    newX_train = pca.fit_transform(newX_train).astype(np.float32)

    valid_components = pca.n_components_
    print(f"Valid components: {valid_components}")

    newX_test = pca.transform(newX_test).astype(np.float32)
    newX_train = np.reshape(newX_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], valid_components))
    newX_test = np.reshape(newX_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], X_test.shape[2], valid_components))

    return newX_train, newX_test, pca

def padWithZeros(X, margin=2):
    newX = np.zeros((X.shape[0] + 2 * margin, X.shape[1] + 2 * margin, X.shape[2]), dtype=np.float32)
    x_offset = margin
    y_offset = margin
    newX[x_offset:X.shape[0] + x_offset, y_offset:X.shape[1] + y_offset, :] = X.astype(np.float32)
    return newX

def createImageCubesWithMask(X, y, mask, mask_type, windowSize=13):
    margin = int((windowSize - 1) / 2)
    print(f"Margin: {margin}")
    zeroPaddedX = padWithZeros(X, margin=margin)
    print(f"Padded X shape: {zeroPaddedX.shape}")
    positions = np.argwhere(mask >= 1)
    patchesData = np.zeros((len(positions), windowSize, windowSize, X.shape[2]), dtype=np.float32)
    patchesLabels = np.zeros(len(positions))

    unique, counts = np.unique(mask, return_counts=True)
    mask_stats = dict(zip(unique, counts))
    print(f"{mask_type} statistics: {mask_stats}")

    print(f"y shape: {y.shape}, type: {type(y)}")
    print(f"{mask_type} positions shape: {positions.shape}, type: {type(positions)}")
    print("_________________________________________________________________________\n")

    for i, pos in enumerate(positions):
        x, y_pos = pos
        x_padded = x + margin
        y_padded = y_pos + margin
        patch = zeroPaddedX[x_padded - margin:x_padded + margin + 1, y_padded - margin:y_padded + margin + 1, :].astype(np.float32)
        patchesData[i, :, :, :] = patch
        patchesLabels[i] = y[x, y_pos] - 1

    return patchesData, patchesLabels

def createImageCubes(X, y, windowSize=13, removeZeroLabels=True):
    margin = int((windowSize - 1) / 2)
    zeroPaddedX = padWithZeros(X, margin=margin)
    patchesData = np.zeros((X.shape[0] * X.shape[1], windowSize, windowSize, X.shape[2]), dtype=np.float32)
    patchesLabels = np.zeros((X.shape[0] * X.shape[1]))
    patchIndex = 0
    for r in range(margin, zeroPaddedX.shape[0] - margin):
        for c in range(margin, zeroPaddedX.shape[1] - margin):
            patch = zeroPaddedX[r - margin:r + margin + 1, c - margin:c + margin + 1].astype(np.float32)
            patchesData[patchIndex, :, :, :] = patch
            patchesLabels[patchIndex] = y[r-margin, c-margin]
            patchIndex = patchIndex + 1
    if removeZeroLabels:
        patchesData = patchesData[patchesLabels > 0, :, :, :]
        patchesLabels = patchesLabels[patchesLabels > 0]
        patchesLabels -= 1

    return patchesData, patchesLabels

def create_data_loader(dataset, kaggle_json_path, patch_size, train_samples):
    X, y, train_mask, test_mask = loadDataWrapper(dataset, kaggle_json_path, train_samples)
    pca_components = 30

    print('Hyperspectral data shape: ', X.shape)
    print('Label shape: ', y.shape)

    print(f'Train mask shape: {train_mask.shape}')
    print(f'Test mask shape: {test_mask.shape}')

    print(f"Patch (window) size: {patch_size}")

    print('\n... ... Create data cubes with masks (Before PCA to avoid data leakage) ... ...')
    Xtrain, ytrain = createImageCubesWithMask(X, y, train_mask, mask_type="Training mask", windowSize=patch_size)
    Xtest, ytest = createImageCubesWithMask(X, y, test_mask, mask_type="Testing mask", windowSize=patch_size)
    print('Xtrain shape: ', Xtrain.shape)
    print('Xtest shape: ', Xtest.shape)
    print('ytrain shape: ', ytrain.shape)
    print('ytest shape: ', ytest.shape)

    gc.collect()

    print('\n... ... PCA tranformation ... ...')
    X_train_pca, X_test_pca, pca_model = applyPCA(Xtrain, Xtest, pca_components)
    print('Xtrain shape after PCA: ', X_train_pca.shape)
    print('Xtest shape after PCA: ', X_test_pca.shape)

    X_train_pca = X_train_pca.reshape(-1, patch_size, patch_size, pca_model.n_components_, 1)
    X_test_pca = X_test_pca.reshape(-1, patch_size, patch_size, pca_model.n_components_, 1)
    print('before transpose: Xtrain shape: ', X_train_pca.shape)
    print('before transpose: Xtest shape: ', X_test_pca.shape)

    X_train_pca = X_train_pca.transpose(0, 4, 3, 1, 2)
    X_test_pca = X_test_pca.transpose(0, 4, 3, 1, 2)
    print('after transpose: Xtrain shape: ', X_train_pca.shape)
    print('after transpose: Xtest shape: ', X_test_pca.shape)

    trainset = TrainDS(X_train_pca, ytrain)
    testset = TestDS(X_test_pca, ytest)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=trainset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=testset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

    gc.collect()

    newX = np.reshape(X, (-1, X.shape[-1])).astype(np.float32)
    X_pca_full = pca_model.transform(newX).astype(np.float32)
    X_pca_full = np.reshape(X_pca_full, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], pca_model.n_components_))

    X_pca_full, y_all = createImageCubes(X_pca_full, y, windowSize=patch_size)
    X_pca_full = X_pca_full.reshape(-1, patch_size, patch_size, pca_model.n_components_, 1)
    X_pca_full = X_pca_full.transpose(0, 4, 3, 1, 2)
    all_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=TestDS(X_pca_full, y_all), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

    return train_loader, test_loader, all_data_loader, y, pca_model.n_components_

def train(train_loader, num_classes, pca_components, lr, dropout, num_tokens, heads, epochs=100):
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print(f"PCA components passed: {pca_components}")
    net = SSFTTnet.SSFTTnet(
        in_channels=1,
        num_classes=num_classes,
        pca_components=pca_components,
        dropout=dropout,
        num_tokens=num_tokens,
        heads=heads).to(device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)

    total_loss = 0
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            outputs = net(data)
            loss = criterion(outputs, target)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            total_loss += loss.item()
        print('[Epoch: %d]   [loss avg: %.4f]   [current loss: %.4f]' % (epoch + 1, total_loss / (epoch + 1), loss.item()))
    print('Finished Training')
    return net, device

def test(device, net, test_loader):
    count = 0
    net.eval()
    y_pred_test = 0
    y_test = 0
    for inputs, labels in test_loader:
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        outputs = net(inputs)
        outputs = np.argmax(outputs.detach().cpu().numpy(), axis=1)
        if count == 0:
            y_pred_test = outputs
            y_test = labels
            count = 1
        else:
            y_pred_test = np.concatenate((y_pred_test, outputs))
            y_test = np.concatenate((y_test, labels))

    return y_pred_test, y_test

